# Como receber um input durante uma função do R?

Tags: r, funções, programação-funcional

É possível fazer uma pergunta e receber um input durante a execução de uma função?

Exemplo:

```
formateCdoispontos<-function(){
  print('Tem certeza que quer fazer isso? (S/N)')
  ...
  if(resposta=='N')break
  ...
  }
```

Ou toda a informação está restrita ao input da função?
 Assim:

```
formateCdoispontos<-function(certeza = 'N'){
  if(resposta=='N')break
  ...
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim,uma forma de fazer isso é aplicar a função `readline()` para adquirir input do terminal do usuário.

```
formateCdoispontos <- function(){
  resposta <- readline(prompt = "Tem certeza que quer fazer isso? (S/N)")
  if(resposta=='N')break
  ...
print(paste("Sua resposta foi" resposta))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tambem podemos usar `menu()`:

```
pergunta <- function(){

  sel <- c("Sim", "Não")

  ans <- menu(sel, title = "Tem certeza que quer fazer isso? (S/N)")

  return(paste0('Sua resposta foi ', tolower(sel[[ans]])))
}
```

No console:

```
> pergunta()
Tem certeza que quer fazer isso? (S/N) 

1: Sim
2: Não

Selection: 1
[1] "Sua resposta foi sim"
```